# How to refresh the original page after opening a URL in a new tab in OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a button that opens a url in a new tab. I want the original page, where the button is, to be reloaded, refreshed, after the opening the url in the new tab. Is it possible to do it?

Here is my XML code:

```
 <button name="test" type="object" string="Go!" 
 attrs="{'invisible':[('flag_bom_present','=',False)]}"  />
```

Here is my python code:

```
def test(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    res = {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url', 
            'url': 'http://www.google.com'
          } 
    return res
```

Comment: can you put your actual code?

Comment: I have added the code in the question.