# Is there a way to refresh (reload) a page programmatically in OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

Is there a way to refresh (reload) a page programmatically, inside the python code, in OpenERP? I am aware of {'type': 'ir.actions.client', 'tag' : 'reload' } but this is in function return.

Comment: Website or backend? Why / what is the use case?

Comment: @DanielReis Here is the link for the [use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803788/how-to-refresh-the-original-page-after-opening-a-url-in-a-new-tab-in-openerp)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
for picking in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
    picking.refresh()
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you, Mariusz, for your answer, but it didn't work.

Comment: This is a code snippet from v7 form button action used for GLS integration, where it works fine - do you need it from any other context?

Comment: I don't need it from any other context.

Comment: Here is the code for [use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803788/how-to-refresh-the-original-page-after-opening-a-url-in-a-new-tab-in-openerp)